# Sort three Arrays by Date

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

So I've got three arrays which have the same elements and length but they are sorted differently by one attribute per array.

I want to show each element from each array in a timeline. So that one elements is present tree times which different dates.

how can I do that?

```
this.timeLineData = []
let sortedStart = this.sortArray(this.data, '0')
let sortedExce = this.sortArray(this.data, '1')
let sortedEnd = this.sortArray(this.data, '2')
```

How i sort:

```
if (sortType === '0'){
  return myArr.sort((val1, val2)=> {return <any>new Date(val1.date1) - <any>new Date(val2.date1)})
}
else if (sortType === '1'){
  return myArr.sort((val1, val2)=> {return <any>new Date(val1.date2) - <any>new Date(val2.date2)})
}
else if (sortType === '2'){
  return myArr.sort((val1, val2)=> {return <any>new Date(val1.date3) - <any>new Date(val2.date3)})
}
```

I want to have a output Array that has objects that look like this:

```
class TimeLine {
element: any
date: Date
}
```

Comment: Please show the desired output

Comment: JavaScript's `Array.sort()` function expects Boolean returns of `1, -1, 0` by comparison of two mandatory arguments.  Tailor your output based on the Boolean returned from a conditional, e.g. `return arg1 < arg2 ? -1 : arg1 > arg2 ? 1 : 0`.  [Array.sort()@MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a functional way to do it in Javascript/Typescript, using higher-order functions to create helpers to sort and transform the data based on any of `date1`, `date2` or `date3` properties.

```js
const timeLineData = [{
  date1: '2011-10-9',
  date2: '2011-10-10',
  date3: '2011-10-11',
  element: '123'
}, {
  date1: '2011-10-6',
  date2: '2011-10-7',
  date3: '2011-10-8',
  element: '456'
}, {
  date1: '2011-10-3',
  date2: '2011-10-4',
  date3: '2011-10-5',
  element: '789'
}];

const compare = dateProp => (e1, e2) => {
  return new Date(e1[dateProp]) - new Date(e2[dateProp]);
};

const transform = dateProp => data => {
  return { date: data[dateProp], element: data.element };
};

const sortedStart = timeLineData.sort(compare('date1')).map(transform('date1'));
const sortedExce = timeLineData.sort(compare('date2')).map(transform('date2'));
const sortedEnd = timeLineData.sort(compare('date3')).map(transform('date3'));

console.log('sortedStart:', sortedStart);
console.log('sortedExce:', sortedExce);
console.log('sortedEnd:', sortedEnd);
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

I also face the same issue and found a good solution for sort multiple columns data in Multi-Dimensional array.

Check the below code

```js
(function() {
      function deepsort(){
    var i, order= arguments, L= order.length, tem;
    return a.sort(function(a, b){
        i= 0;
      
        while(i < L){
          
            tem= order[i++];
          var res = tem.split("_");
            var ao= a[res[0]] || 0, bo= b[res[0]] || 0;
            if(ao== bo) continue;
           
          if(res[1] == "ASC"){
            return ao > bo? 1: -1;
          }
          if(res[1] == "DESC"){
             return ao < bo? 1: -1;
          }
        }
        return 0;
    });
}

var a= [
    ["2011-10-9", "2011-10-10", "2011-10-11", 21],
    ["2011-10-6", "2011-10-7", "2011-10-8", 11],
    ["2011-10-3", "2011-10-4", "2011-10-5", 20]
];
document.write(deepsort(0+"_ASC",1+"_ASC"));
// for better result view check console log
console.log(deepsort(0+"_ASC",1+"_ASC"))
//console.log(a.deepsort(1))
    
    })();
```